# Error: send que size more than ABSTRACT_SERVER_SEND_QUE_MAX_COUNT

Tags: monerod, error-log

What does this bitmonerod error mean?

> ERROR   {6} {p1} 2016-07-24 17:47:31.294360 [abstract_tcp_server2.inl+512 ::do_send_chunk] send que size is more than ABSTRACT_SERVER_SEND_QUE_MAX_COUNT(1000), shutting down connection

After restart the node is working again properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means communication with that particular peer is stuck. It can be ignored, and is likely fixed in master (hard to be 100% sure).